# How to add colorkey title to grid.arrange plot

Tags: r

I am plotting raster using levelplot and adding a unit measurement of "mm" to colorkey using the following:

```
raster_plot<-levelplot(ras,margin=F,col.regions=my_colors,at=my.at, colorkey=myColorkey)
raster_plot
trellis.focus("legend", side="right", clipp.off=TRUE, highlight=FALSE)
grid.text(expression(mm), 0.2, 0, hjust=0.3, vjust=1.5)
trellis.unfocus()
```

this works fine if I want to plot a single raster. However if I use `grid.arrange` to plot multiple I am unable to add the legend title.

```
grid.arrange(raster_plot,raster_plot2,raster_plot3,ncol=3,top = textGrob("Visualizing Monsoon Mean Precipitation Patterns",gp=gpar(fontsize=20,font=3)))
```

how can i achieve the same result using grid.arrange?